# How to do multiple vector dot product in a nested list?

Tags: python, numpy

I tried to get a vector dot product in a nested list
For example :

```
A = np.array([[1,2,1,3],[2,1,2,3],[3,1,2,4]])
```

And I tried to get:

```
B = [[15], [19, 23]]
```

Where 15 = np.dot(A[0],A[1]),

19 = np.dot(A[0],A[2]),

23 = np.dot(A[1],A[2])

The fist inner_list in B is the dot product of A[0] and A[1],

The second inner_list in B is
dot product of A[0] and A[2], dot product of A[1] and A[2]
I tried to write some loop in python but failed
How to get B in Python?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your explanation of what you’re trying to do, could you expand on it somehow?

Comment: side note: if you try to do normal for loop, should _not_ use `list` as a variable since it's a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)

Comment: I tried to get B that B[0] is A[1] dot A[0], B[1] is A[0] dot A[2] and A[1] dot A[2],
B[2] will be A[0] dot A[3], A[1] dot A[3], A[2] dot A[3]..and so on

Comment: This one works for me `out = [[np.dot(A[0], A[1])], [np.dot(A[0], A[2]), np.dot(A[1], A[2])]]`. Why do you need for loop? If there are lots of A, then iterate over A's in the above line

Comment: I tried to write a fuction to deal with the situation that if a lot of list nested in A

Comment: if you have lots of nested list, then you need a clear logic to compute it. From your small example it's not clear. I think I got it. Is it each list in the out_list is dot product of N+1 th element with all the previous elements?

Comment: Yeah it is, thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you trying get a `dot` distance between all pairs of rows.  `scipy.spatial.distance` has a `pdist` that does this kind of thing.

Comment: Supplementing to the accepted answer, you could also considering using _iterator_ if you are dealing with a very large array. _list comprehension_ make code more readable; _iterator_ makes the runner optimized since runner can iterate each element **while** processing dot product rather than **after** processing all dot products. I have added an iterator example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a explicit for loop coupled with list comprehension solution:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: A = np.array([[1,2,1,3],[2,1,2,3],[3,1,2,4]])

In [5]: def get_dp(A):
   ...:     out = []
   ...:     for i, a in enumerate(A[1:]):
   ...:         out.append([np.dot(a, b) for b in A[:i+1]])
   ...:     return out

In [6]: get_dp(A)
Out[6]: [[15], [19, 23]]
```

Explanation: The for loop is running from 2nd elements and the list comprehension is running from the beginning to the current iterated element.

Answer (score 0):

An iterator class that spits out elements same as B.
If you want the full list, you can `list(iter_dotprod(A))`

example:

```py
class iter_dotprod:

    def __init__(self, nested_arr):
        self.nested_arr = nested_arr
        self.hist = []

    def __iter__(self):
        self.n = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.n > len(self.nested_arr) -2:
            raise StopIteration

        res = np.dot(self.nested_arr[self.n], self.nested_arr[self.n+1])
        self.hist.append(res)
        self.n += 1
        return self.hist

A = np.array([[1,2,1,3],[2,1,2,3],[3,1,2,4]])
tt = iter_dotprod(A)

for b in iter_dotprod(A):
    print(b)
```